# Не отображается полностью таблица виртуальных функций

Tags: c++, отладка, visual-studio-2017, виртуальная-функция

```
struct Parent {
    virtual void p_f() {

    }
};

struct Child :Parent {
    virtual void c_f() {

    }
};
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что таблица виртуальных функций (ТВФ) `Child` должна содержать два элемента - указатели на `Parent::p_f()` и `Child::c_f()`?

Почему тогда в отладчике (MVS2017) показывает, что ТВФ `Child` содержит только 1 элемент - указатель на `Parent::p_f`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну это же разные функции. Нет никакого замещения. И указатель всегда всего один, указывающий на vtable.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну вот именно, что разные. Я же не переопределяю одну функцию другой. Почему они обе не отображаются?

Comment: Присмотритесь внимательно к строке выше - там четко написано - `::`vftable'[3])` - т.е. в таблице три записи. Добавьте еще одну виртуальную функцию - станет 4... Просто вы ее наследуете от предка, вот она и показывает  ее как таблицу предка - видите слева - Parent?

Comment: @Harry а почему 3? функции же 2. А как посмотреть полное содержимое таблицы `Child`, если таблица предка не интересует?

Comment: А вы точно знаете спецификацию таблицы виртуальных функций в реализации VisualC++? Что именно там должно быть? :) Может, там завершающий нулевой указатель, например... А что до как посмотреть - честно говоря, я туда обычно не лажу, тут надо кто-то, кто со средой хорошо умеет работать, мне обычно проще и быстрее по старинке, отладочным выводом ошибки найти, чем в среде копаться...

Comment: Ну, покопался... Можно открыть Отладка-Окно-Память, ввести адрес, который содержит __vfptr, и посмотреть там на список адресов. Похоже, кстати, что я угадал, и последний адрес в vtable - просто нулевой :) Ну, как признак окончания, наверное...